# Como ejecuto dos eventos al mismo tiempo?

Tags: c#, hilos, eventos

Estoy desarrollando un juego el cual es para 2 jugadores, en el cual dos picture box deben moverse si se presiona la tecla W o S un PictureBox se mueve, y si se presiona Tecla Up o Tecla Down debe moverse el otro pictureBox, pero ambos deben reaccionar al mismo tiempo. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahorita, funciona, pero o un pictureBox se mueve o el otro, pero no al mismo tiempo

Comment: podrias mostrarnos que hiciste hasta ahora???

Comment: Si, ya edite mi pregunta, ahi esta el ejemplo, si funciona, pero no se mueven al mismo tiempo.

Comment: es lo correcto segun tu codigo.. y aunque lo pongas en hilos, se va a ejecutar un hilo antes que el otro.. necesitarias algo mejor que este lenguaje para eso...

Comment: Pues tu codigo no dice mucho, pero lo unico que deberias de hacer es tener dos thread (hilos) corriendo, uno para cada jugador, ademas de que hoy en dia muchas cosas son orientas a objetos y lo mismo deberias de estar haciendo, es decir crear el juego pensando en solo un jugador y luego agregar tantos jugadores sean necesarios, se que mas que una respuesta en un sugerencia o idea con la cual puedas solucionar tu problema

Comment: Es que ya lo hize en Java, pero no es tan diferente a esto, solo que haya lo hice con timers, intente hacerlo asi pero salio el problema citado

Comment: la clave es al mismo tiempo, eso depende del observador, asi que yo te recomiendo que no refresques la pantalla hasta que los dos jugadores se hayan movido, de esta manera para los jugadores todo habra ocurrido a la vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses lo siguiente:

```
//otros using
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Ejemplo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys teclas);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 teclas);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0;  i<=255; i++)
            {
                int numcontrol = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                if (numcontrol == -32767) // Verificamos si numcontrol fue 
realmente presionado controlando que numcontrol sea -32767 
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Up)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Up");
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Down)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Down");
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.W)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("W");
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.W)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("S");
                    }
                }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Agregas un Timer en el control de Windows, de das doble click y te hará el evento Tick, el cual escuchará cuando se haga algo sobre el control, ya sea click o una tecla y de ahí verificas cual tecla se presionó y llamar a lo que desees hacer.

Comment: muchas gracias ya pude resolverlo gracias a esto :)